# Contacts see me Offline on WLM Althoung I'm online and chatting with them

Tags: windows, windows-live-messenger

this problem appears just **a few days ago** , and still till this moment , 
my problem is that Contacts in my Windows Live Messenger (**Version :14.0.8089.726** ) told me that I'm offline **while I'm online** , some of theme told me that I log in and out every moment while I'm still log in , after that they see me online again , 
so what is the problem exactly , and how can I get rid of it ?

***Notice* : I think problem started after they (Windows Live) make the feature that you can sign in from 2 messengers at same time .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i was searching about the problem i found that it happening alot for many WLM users, anyways i found this comment and it might help you:

---

I understand that you're still appearing offline to your contacts even you're online. I know this is quite inconvenient. Allow me to guide you in resolving this.

From our investigation, this issue usually happens when the Messenger cache folder of your account stored in your computer is corrupted. It is also possible your contacts are moved to your allow or block lists.

To resolve your issue, I will be giving to you the steps to delete the corrupted Messenger cache folder of your account stored in your computer. I have also included the steps to verify if those contacts that see you as offline are moved to allow or block lists.

Note: To fix the problem, please make sure that you and your friends follow these steps:

Step 1
- Here are the steps to delete Messenger cache folder:

- Right-click the Start button and then click Explore. In the window that opens, On the Tools menu beside Favorites and Help menu, click Folder Options. Click the View tab, and then make sure that Show Hidden files and folders option is selected.

Note: After you delete Messenger cache folder, it will regenerated a new and fresh copy of Messenger cache folder in your computer.

For Windows XP user, here are the steps:

1. Click Start, click Run, copy and paste this message %USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\ and then press Enter. Delete the IdentityCRL folder.
2. Click Start, click Run, copy and paste this message %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\ and then press Enter. Delete the IdentityCRL folder.
3. Click Start, click Run, copy and paste this message %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\ and then press Enter. Delete the Windows Live Contacts folder.
4. Click Start, click Run, copy and paste this message %USERPROFILE% and then press Enter. Delete the Contacts folder.

For Windows Vista users, here are the steps:

1. Click Start, copy and paste this message in the Start Search box %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\ and then press Enter. Delete the Windows Live Contacts folder.
2. Click Start, copy and paste this message in the Start Search box %userprofile% and the press Enter. Delete the Contacts folder.
3. Sign in to Windows Live Messenger.

Step 2
- Try to sign in to Messenger and verify if the issue still persists.

If the issue still persists, it's possible that your contacts are move to your allow or block lists.

Here are the steps on how you'll appear online to you contacts once you performed completely these steps:

Here are the steps to re-add the contact that moved to Allow list:

1.Sign in to Windows Live Messenger.
2.On the Tools menu, click Options and then click Privacy.
3.From the Allow list, right-click the contact that was deleted previously and then click Add to Contacts.
4.Click OK.

Here are the steps to re-add the contact that moved to Block list:

1.Sign in to Windows Live Messenger.
2.On the Tools menu, click Options and then click Privacy.
3.From the Block list, right-click the contact that was previously block and deleted and then click Add to contacts and Move to allow list.
4.Click Apply, and then OK.

---

Link: http://www.vistax64.com/windows-live/213505-problem-windows-live-messenger-appearing-offline-2.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if/how you solved this issue, but I think this might help someone else; I'm having the same problem with a fresh LiveID, so I guess it's a server problem.

I see that contacts I've added through the WLM interface appear as blocked.

My guess is, since there is no more a "blocked" status on WLM2011, they are then using the blocked flag for something else;

in particular, I think they are trying to link the profiles (along with their "social updates") to the WLM contacts. If you and your contact can't see online each other (you or him/her) try and see if one of you has a pending friend request on his/her live profile.

I think your contact appears to you as "blocked" when (s)he hasn't still accepted you on his/her live profile.

Once accepted, both of you log out and back in, and see if something has changed.

While the change (similar to what Facebook does, only on FB you accept the friend request once and for all) makes sense, it makes very little sense to do it like this.

HTH

Comment: This answer catalysed the solution for me. Each of us went to our profile on Live, and under "view invitations" one of us still had an outstanding invite from the other. Once this was accepted, we could both see the other as 'online'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Did you try to check that you didn't make your status "Appear as Offline"?
- It could be a virus or  a piece of malware. Try to run a antivirus scan and a malware scan.

Comment: Yes I did , my status if "On line" , and I have MS security essentials .